# function return zero always

Tags: php, mysql, function

### a.php

```
include 'function.php';

$avg = get_ecomm_avg_rating();
echo "Avg rating :- $avg";
```

### function.php

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("myserver","abc","red", "live");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) 
{
printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
exit();
}

function get_ecomm_avg_rating()
{
    $query = "SELECT AVG(ROUND((r.ratings_sum / r.ratings_qty),1)) AS total_rating
        FROM abc AS c, xyz AS r
        WHERE c.store
        IN (994,094) 
        AND r.reviewid = c.id
        AND c.published =  '1'";

    $avg_rating_result = mysqli_query($conn,$query); 
    $avg_rating_row = mysqli_fetch_array($avg_rating_result); 
    $avg_rating_count = $avg_rating_row[0];
    $avg_rating_count_final = number_format($avg_rating_count, 1);

    return $avg_rating_count_final;

}
```

Always return 0.0. What should I do? Any batter approach? I'm New to functions and PHP

Comment: Variable `$conn` doens't exists in the body of function

Comment: same result .. If I tried directly to a.php working perfect//

Comment: `function get_ecomm_avg_rating($storeno)` | `$avg = get_ecomm_avg_rating();`. missing `$storeno` function parameter.

Comment: @back123 Does `$conn` exist within the function? If it's outside then your function still can't use it.

Comment: Can you verify the SQL itself is producing the result you expect? Can you test it in PHPMyAdmin for example?

Comment: You should post the real code and not change it based on the answers and comments you get.

Comment: Ahh scope... already answered by panther! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a problem with a variable scope, var `$conn` doesn't exists in the function.

You need to add this var by parameter:

```
function get_ecomm_avg_rating($conn, $storeno) {
    ....
}

// and here when calling the function you pass there a DB connection
$avg = get_ecomm_avg_rating($conn);

// $conn has to be defined elsewhere, like $conn = mysqli_connect(...)
```

Then, you have there parameter `$storeno` which is unused.